# CodeIgniter deleting with db doesnt work

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am doing an ajax call..which doesnt output any mysql errors..Basically, I am trying to delete two records...

```
  public function task_delete($task_id)
     {
            $this->load->database();
            $this->db->delete('task_pages', array('id' => $task_id));
            $this->db->delete('tasks', array('id' => $task_id));

       }
```

This is the model..

And this is the controller..

```
class Ajax extends CI_Controller {

       public function delete()
      {
          $this->load->database();
          $this->load->model('tasks_model','task_delete');
          $result=$this->task_delete-> task_delete($this->input->post('myId'));
          echo $result;
      }

}
```

Where does my code fails?

UPDATE:
I get an error..the method deleteTask is being called on none object

Comment: Your function is `task_delete`, but you're calling `deleteTask`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your model is also called task_delete and the function you want to call is deleteTask, then you have given the function in your model the wrong name, it should be declared as this:

```
public function deleteTask($task_id)
```

Comment: i fixed that it says that the where method is called on non object

Comment: Have you loaded the model into your app/controller? `$this->load->model('task_delete');` or if you controller isn't called task_delete, `$this->load->model('Model_name', 'task_delete');`. Taken from http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html